# Why setting null in the middle of std string doesn't have any effect

Tags: c++, stdstring

Consider

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    /*
    hello
    5
    hel
    3
    */
    char a[] = "hello";
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << strlen(a) << std::endl;
    a[3] = 0;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << strlen(a) << std::endl;

    /*
    hello
    5
    hel o
    5
    */
    std::string b = "hello";
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.length() << std::endl;
    b[3] = 0;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.length() << std::endl;

    getchar();

}
```

I expect `std::string` will behave identical to `char` array a. That's it, insert null character in the middle of the string, will "terminate" the string. However, it is not the case. Is my expectation wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `std::string` is not like a usual C string, and can contain embedded NUL characters without problems. However, if you do this you will notice the string is prematurely terminated if you use the `.c_str()` function to return a `const char *`.

Answer (score 4):

No - `std::string`s are not NUL-terminated like C "strings"; the std::string records its length independently.

Answer (score 2):

@Lou is right: don't do that. Instead, do this:

```
b.erase (3, b.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your expectation is wrong.  `std::string` is *meant* to be different from C strings (e.g. not necessarily stored in consecutive memory / an array).

To duplicate the first section's behavior, try `std::cout << b.c_str()` instead of `std::cout << b`.

Comment: Can't we finally give up on the theory that anyone is ever going to implement `string` with non-contiguous storage? C++0x brings it in line with `vector`.

Comment: With that comment, you might just provoke somebody into actually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

*I expect std::string will behave identical to char array a.*

Why?  Nothing in the documentation, anywhere, having to do with std::string says it does this.

My suggestion, stop treating like C++ as C plus some stuff.