# Get size of a std::string's string in bytes

Tags: c++, string, multibyte

I would like to get the bytes a `std::string`'s string occupies in memory, not the number of characters. The string contains a multibyte string. Would `std::string::size()` do this for me?

EDIT: Also, does `size()` also include the terminating `NULL`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::string` operates on bytes, not on Unicode characters, so `std::string::size()` will indeed return the size of the data in bytes (without the overhead that `std::string` needs to store the data, of course).

No, `std::string` stores only the data you tell it to store (it does not need the trailing `NULL` character). So it will not be included in the size, unless you explicitly create a string with a trailing `NULL` character.

Comment: Is it valid to say that std::string is the same as an char array? Or are there any major differences?

Comment: Yes, char array is exactly what `std::string` is. There are some implementation differences between `std::string` and `std::vector<char>`, but the data they are storing is the same.

Comment: just want to point out that the reason `std::string::size()` doesn't include the `NULL` character is to follow the convention set by `strlen` which also doesn't include it. Actual implementations of `std::string` do require the *storage* for the terminating `NULL`, in order to implement the `string::c_str()` method with minimal overhead. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4653745) explains better than I do.

Comment: While the `size()` does not consider the trailing `0`, the fact is that most implementations will keep a trailing NUL. The standard requires that `static_cast<const std::string&>(str)[str.size()]` yields `0` (casted to the appropriate `charT` type) and in many implementations that is achieved by always keeping an extra `0` at the end (arguably, it could be implemented with a condition in `operator[]`). The upcoming standard extends that guarantee to the non-const `operator[]`. Also, there is no guarantee that the implementation does not allocate extra space, i.e. `capacity() >= size()`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful insights, Lukáš, rwong and David.

Answer (score 12):

You could be pedantic about it:

```
std::string x("X");

std::cout << x.size() * sizeof(std::string::value_type);
```

But `std::string::value_type` is `char` and `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1`.

This only becomes important if you `typedef` the string type (because it may change in the future or because of compiler options).

```
// Some header file:
typedef   std::basic_string<T_CHAR>  T_string;

// Source a million miles away
T_string   x("X");

std::cout << x.size() * sizeof(T_string::value_type);
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::string::size()` is indeed the size in bytes.

Answer (score 5):

To get the amount of memory in use by the string you would have to sum the `capacity()` with the overhead used for management. Note that it is `capacity()` and not `size()`. The capacity determines the number of characters (`charT`) allocated, while `size()` tells you how many of them are actually in use.

In particular, `std::string` implementations don't usually *shrink_to_fit* the contents, so if you create a string and then remove elements from the end, the `size()` will be decremented, but in most cases (this is implementation defined) `capacity()` will not.

Some implementations might not allocate the exact amount of memory required, but rather obtain blocks of given sizes to reduce memory fragmentation. In an implementation that used power of two sized blocks for the strings, a string with size `17` could be allocating as much as `32` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, size() will give you the number of `char` in the string.  One character in multibyte encoding take up multiple `char`.

Answer (score 0):

There is inherent conflict in the question as written:  `std::string` is defined as `std::basic_string<char,...>` -- that is, its element type is `char` (1-byte), but later you stated "the string contains a multibyte string" ("multibyte" == `wchar_t`?).

The `size()` member function does not count a trailing null.  It's value represents the number of characters (not bytes).

Assuming you intended to say your multibyte string is `std::wstring` (alias for `std::basic_string<wchar_t,...>`), the memory footprint for the `std::wstring`'s characters, including the null-terminator is:

```
std::wstring myString;
 ...
size_t bytesCount = (myString.size() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
```

It's instructive to consider how one would write a reusable template function that would work for ANY potential instantiation of std::basic_string<> like this**:

```
// Return number of bytes occupied by null-terminated inString.c_str().
template <typename _Elem>
inline size_t stringBytes(const std::basic_string<typename _Elem>& inString, bool bCountNull)
{
   return (inString.size() + (bCountNull ? 1 : 0)) * sizeof(_Elem);
}
```

** For simplicity, ignores the traits and allocator types rarely specified explicitly for `std::basic_string<>` (they have defaults).